# parameter-passing: passing the string value into functions

Tags: jquery, focus, parameter-passing, each, blur

I want to pass the string value which I get from the textarea into the focus() and blur(),
but why what I will get is [object object]?

I get the string value of each textarea successfully with each() and I store the string in a var - `var value_default = $this.val();`

Then I pass this `var` into `$this.focus(function (value_default) {..})` - am I passing it incorrectly?

If I alert this `value_default` I will get [object oject] - alert(value_default);

Below is the entire code if you need to see it...

```
$(".autohide").each(function(){

    /* set the variable and store its value */
    var $this = $(this);

    var value_default = $this.val();

    var parent_autohide = $this.parents('form');

    var parent_button = $('input[type=submit]',parent_autohide).parents("div:.item-form").hide();


    var parent_marginbottom = parseInt($this.parents("div:.item-form").css("marginBottom"));

    $this.parents("div:.item-form").css({margin:'0px'});

    alert(value_default); // I will get the string value of each textarea element

    $this.focus(function (value_default) {

        alert(value_default); // I will get [object object]

        var $this = $(this);

        $this.elastic();

        $this.parents('div:.item-form').css({margin:'0px 0px '+parent_marginbottom+'px 0px'});

        var $this_parent = $this.parents('form');

        var $this_button =  $('input[type=submit]',$this_parent).parents("div:.item-form").show();


    }).blur(function(value_default){

        alert(value_default); // I will get [object object]

        var $this = $(this);

        var value_current = $this.val();

        if ( value_current == value_default) 
        {
            $this.css({ height: 'inherit'});

            $this.parents('div:.item-form').css({margin:'0px'});

            var $this_parent = $this.parents('form');

            var $this_button =  $('input[type=submit]',$this_parent).parents("div:.item-form").hide();

        }
    });

});
```

many thanks.

edit:

I know what was causing the error on IE -

```
$this.css({height: 'inherit'}); // this line will create error on IE

$this.css({height:''}); // IE likes this
```

so what is wrong with 'inherit' that IE won't take it like other browsers!??

Comment: In this case `$this.focus(function (value_default) {..})` you aren't actually passing `value_default` to the function.   You are defining a function where `value_default` is the first argument (which in this case will be the event object sent from the focus event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenter has said, the function you create that handles the focus and the blur has the first parameter (event parameter) defined as value_default, which is overriding the one you declare higher up.

So it should work if you just do:

`.focus(function(){` and `.blur(function(){`

Thus you should be able to access the value_default you declare before as it is still within scope and not being overridden by your function parameters.

Comment: This seems risky to me.  The value of `value_default` on all blur/focus events will end up being the last value seen (I think).  http://jsfiddle.net/CcdWt/ -- click on all three divs and you get the value of "test3" (correct me if I set this up wrong)

Comment: If you add the var keyword before the t in your example it works. That way the t is within scope of your function and not global. I've updated your example on jsfiddle.

Comment: @laurencek - I must not set the var to global bcos I have other textareas with different default text values...

Comment: That IE7 error could really be from anything, and as I don't have a complete version of your code I cannot really help.

Comment: @laurencek: I think that is the only code causing the error on IE as far as I found. if I take out that code entirely, the IE will work fine. Here is the link to see the IE error. try to click on the textarea field first then click on other input field, then u will see the error on IE http://rokhsanafiaz.co.uk/forum/forum-category-a/public-forum-3 thanks